# words in .js file for a slide is organized strangely with '|' separators

Tags: javascript, text, slide

I have the source files of an online course. The content is a slideshow. Each slide is build with a .swf file and .js file. The swf file contains an image displayed on the slide, and the .js file contains texts on the slide.

However, I cannot understand the .js file: the words are organized in such a strange way that instead of having a whole paragraph, the texts are broken into individual words and each word is pinned on the slide with a position parameter. Also, the words are separated by '|'

**Just wondering if anyone has seen this type of code and knows what is going on???**

Here is the slide:
[an example slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHlhG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAuEX.png)

And here is the .js file that correspond to this slide. You can see that all words on the slide can be found in the messy .js code. :
`eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?"":e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1;};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p;}('5N("3g","<5g 5b:5P=\'5p://5k.5l.4V/4W/4O-5R\' 5b:5M=\'5p://5k.5l.4V/4W/4O\' h=\'3g\' U=\'5I\' V=\'5H\' 1a=\'d\' 1A=\'d\' 5J=\'g\' 5L=\'g\' 5K=\'5S\' 62=\'-1\' 5Z=\'2r\' 63=\'2i/53/3g.2I\' 65=\'3W/53/3g.64\' 5Y=\'3e 2J 3j 3a\' 5U=\'g\' 5T=\'d\' 5V=\'\' 5X=\'\' 5W=\'\' 1z=\'d\' 1l=\'1j\' 5r=\'0\' 5t=\'1\' 5s=\'d\' 5v=\'d\' 5G=\'-1\' 5z=\'\' 6y=\'\' 6B=\'\'><29><E h=\'57\'><e><2F 3O=\'3U\' 3S=\'2r\'><f b=\'c\' a=\'1g.3s.6U\' /></2F></e></E><E h=\'59\'><e><2F 3O=\'3U\' 3S=\'2r\'><f b=\'c\' a=\'1g.3s.4e\' /></2F></e></E><E h=\'5j\'><e><G h=\'59\' /></e></E><E h=\'4T\'><e><G h=\'57\' /></e></E></29><1k><50><e><3r 1l=\'1j\' 1e=\'0\' 1p=\'0\' 1n=\'\' 1o=\'d\'><f b=\'c\' a=\'1u\' /></3r><3r 1l=\'1j\' 1e=\'0\' 1p=\'0\' 1n=\'\' 1o=\'d\'><f b=\'c\' a=\'1u.1u\' /></3r><m><j><p><p><B n=\'A\' C=\'1g.2v\' D=\'F\' z=\'d\' w=\'o\' /></p></p></j><k><J 1l=\'1j\' 1e=\'0\' 1p=\'0\' 1n=\'\' 1o=\'d\'><f b=\'c\' a=\'1i\' /></J><m><j><B n=\'A\' C=\'1i.1Q\' D=\'F\' z=\'2S\' w=\'c\' /></j><k><G h=\'1i.1V\' /><G h=\'1i.1c\' /></k><y><q I=\'1i.1Q\' n=\'T\'><a b=\'c\' a=\'2S\' /></q><q I=\'1i.1R\' n=\'T\'><a b=\'o\' a=\'d\' /></q><G h=\'1i.1V\' /><r><W b=\'c\' a=\'2S\' /><f b=\'c\' a=\'1i\' /></r><G h=\'1i.1c\' /></y></m></k></m><m><j><p><p><B n=\'A\' C=\'1g.2v\' D=\'F\' z=\'g\' w=\'o\' /></p></p></j><k><J 1l=\'1j\' 1e=\'0\' 1p=\'0\' 1n=\'\' 1o=\'d\'><f b=\'c\' a=\'1i\' /></J><m><j><B n=\'A\' C=\'1i.1Q\' D=\'F\' z=\'1h\' w=\'c\' /></j><k><G h=\'1i.1V\' /><G h=\'1i.1c\' /></k><y><q I=\'1i.1Q\' n=\'T\'><a b=\'c\' a=\'1h\' /></q><q I=\'1i.1R\' n=\'T\'><a b=\'o\' a=\'d\' /></q><G h=\'1i.1V\' /><r><W b=\'c\' a=\'1h\' /><f b=\'c\' a=\'1i\' /></r><G h=\'1i.1c\' /></y></m></k></m><m><j><p><p><B n=\'A\' C=\'1g.4c\' D=\'F\' z=\'d\' w=\'o\' /></p></p></j><k><6S H=\'52\' 6V=\'d\' /><6M H=\'52\' 6Q=\'g\' /></k></m></e></50><4X><e><m><j><B n=\'A\' C=\'6O\' D=\'2W\' z=\'6g\' w=\'c\' /></j><k><6f H=\'4P\' /></k><y><66 H=\'4P\' /></y></m></e></4X><4U><e><G h=\'4T\' /></e></4U><5o 6r=\'1g.2v\' 6w=\'0\'><e><m><j><p><p><B n=\'A\' C=\'1g.2v\' D=\'F\' z=\'g\' w=\'o\' /></p></p></j><k><J 1l=\'1j\' 1e=\'0\' 1p=\'0\' 1n=\'\' 1o=\'d\'><f b=\'c\' a=\'1i\' /></J><m><j><B n=\'A\' C=\'1i.1Q\' D=\'F\' z=\'1h\' w=\'c\' /></j><k><G h=\'1i.1V\' /><G h=\'1i.1c\' /></k><y><q I=\'1i.1Q\' n=\'T\'><a b=\'c\' a=\'1h\' /></q><q I=\'1i.1R\' n=\'T\'><a b=\'o\' a=\'d\' /></q><G h=\'1i.1V\' /><r><W b=\'c\' a=\'1h\' /><f b=\'c\' a=\'1i\' /></r><G h=\'1i.1c\' 1e=\'7P\'><1k><2p><e><q I=\'1g.2s\' n=\'T\'><a b=\'o\' a=\'g\' /></q></e></2p></1k></2u></5e><7O h=\'7z\' /></5g>");',62,561,'||||||||||value|type|string|false|actions|objref|true|id||condition|then_actions||if_action|operator|boolean|and|adjustvar|setobjstate|100|data|vectordata|_parent|typeb|state|else_actions|valueb|eq|compare|valuea|typea|actiongroup|var|exe_actiongroup|name|variable|show|pngfb|Lib|bottom|pr|left|top|right|_this|vectortext|set|width|height|stateref|alttext|accstate|hotlinkid|||||||||||resume|xpos|_setstates|ypos|duration|alpha|_player|_default|61VeR1VJfCj|appear|events|transition|rotation|animationid|reverse|direction|media_play|textdata|media_seek|object_action|6Rr5xAuAgjM|media_pause|onobjectevent|color|objects|scrolling|usehandcursor|yoffset|rotateypos|rotatexpos|shufflelock|depth|xscale|yscale|xoffset|6qdAJvwxENn|shapemaskid|tabindex|colors|tabenabled|OK|vectorshape|_state|_disabled|_hover|textlib|fill|ActGrpClearStateVars|linkid|_down|shadowindex|01|clickdef|eventname||position|command|ontransitionin|bringtofront|onrelease||actiongroups|stop|rgb|variables|acctype|defaultaction|_default_Hover|6h4h6dlJXQM|6Tvl9vSIUCs|story_content|xA|_visited|imagelib|onrollout|set_enabled|states|onmediacomplete|onrollover|normal|Slide73|url|audio|OKSlide06|6h4h6dlJXQM_expandinglabel|linear|6cTc2LTNjRe|5py3rKbJMcJ|6Tvl9vSIUCs_expandinglabel|6Rr5xAuAgjM_expandinglabel|6aApAQhr65J|hidecomplete|_default_Disabled|gotoplay|contentheight|actionstates|swf|to|stategroup|expandinglabel|ActGrpClearHoverState|Marker|ActGrpSetHoverState|252|contentincomplete|scrollarea|NotActive|_show|contentoutcomplete|onclickoutside|property|176|text|your|||||||||182|the|Data|you|enabled|HR|Access|in|5uQ7FzsmKWa|event|imagedata|Personal|mobiledy|mobiledx|mp3|button|are|408|66oTcWg8KdJ|hide|5ofRKrG1Amb|Expanded|_savevisited|Slide72|_glow|Slide7|bg|border|showcomplete|animationtype|177|content_scroll_6h4h6dlJXQM|full|2500|126|of|content_scroll_6Rr5xAuAgjM|0xE8E8E8|Slide71|262|requirements|togglecontent|window|role|arrowypos|120|wndtype|arrowxpos|_current|contentwidth|mobile|showclosebutton|borderwidth|IMDL|||content_scroll_6Tvl9vSIUCs|timeline|5kCvCOThp34|661|_default_Down|onreleaseoutside|_default_Visited||_default_Visited_Down|_default_Visited_Disabled|Slide6Next|ActGrpSetVisitedState|6ReLetnWS8G|onpress|ActGrpSetDownState|_default_Hover_Down|NotActive_Visited_Down|NotActive_Hover|NotActive_Visited_Disabled|NotActive_Visited|NotActive_Disabled|_default_Hover_Visited_Down|_default_Hover_Visited|NotActive_Hover_Visited_Down|NotActive_Hover_Down|NotActive_Hover_Visited|typing|Sitting|sure|6UXX6xozPGr|6FBFn9dgYsp_X_80_DX706_DY706_CX353_CY350|350|353|Male|expression|Talking|5s8T21KeDep|6UEzWWqBnPH|as|objgroup|ActGrpSetDisabledState|NotActive_Down|know|355|6imEZ4VlRP2|253|344|time|XMLSchema|pxnsnfns0001000101|122|204|6IDLsta40MJ|NavigationRestrictionPreviousSlide_5uQ7FzsmKWa|onprevslide|org|2001|onbeforeslidein|for|409|onslidestart|laws|next|slides|You|247||ActGrpOnPrevButtonClick||ActGrpOnNextButtonClick|418|xmlns|0x7E9632|onnextslide|audiolib|background|slide|may|countries|NavigationRestrictionNextSlide_5uQ7FzsmKWa|www|w3|128|have|onvarchanged|http|255|transduration|wipetrans|transdir|that|slidelock|obligations|accessing|339|globalaudioid|376|txt__default_6imEZ4VlRP2|476|when|618|377|navindex|540|720|enableseek|lmsid|enablereplay|xsd|SlideXMLData|600000|xsi|378|instance|Slide10|showmenuresulticon|trackviews|viewgroupid|videozoom|historygroupid|title|elapsedtimemode|||starttime|dataurl|gz|iosurl|set_window_control_layout|maskref|371||altimage|png|mobileimage|278|tabchildren|set_frame_layout|_frame|337|185|139|LastSlideViewed_6ofAvNJC6Jl|167|175|1000|0xFFFFFF|AbsoluteId|image|varname|706|700|374|6FBFn9dgYsp_X_80_DX706_DY706|priority|131|thumbnailid|extent|which|showanimationid|rights|well|exercise|external|audit|Make|them|subject|internal|263|enable_window_control|Rounded|WindowId|125|enable|Rectangular|set_window_control_visible|172|6ZL0ql9YJKJ|visible|Caption|375|387|183||161||275||txt__default_6ab83UwLznJ|385|||Center|386|txt__default_5s8T21KeDep|Many|388|processing|established|Remember|0xCFDFA9|404|0xC0D589|0xC6D89B|Identity|portal|System|Management|such|by|granted|request|proper|contact|responsibilities|Contact|SSC|scope|none|If|supports|what|391|txt__default_5mXkvwUWUna|393|392|390|those|with|txt__default_6IDLsta40MJ|389|6VTUFrqvVFm_22050_56|24035|presenterref|12660|5oLHx1Iws1F_22050_56|4553|5xkSBaKzSHq_22050_56|24410|6mf4PCo8laK_22050_56|reflected|they|Framework|Protection|same|broad|||The|||these|principles||on|supervisor|comply|country|consult|some|However|should|specific|txt__default_Disabled_61VeR1VJfCj|action|380|03|210|Missing|hover|over|star|02|Please|txt__default_61VeR1VJfCj|379|583|480|06|txt_NotActive_61VeR1VJfCj|txt__default_Hover_61VeR1VJfCj|04|txt__default_Down_61VeR1VJfCj|196|192|05|txt__default_Visited_61VeR1VJfCj|marker|txt__default_5guKkYHzZX2|146|not|382|216|383|248|0xCEDEA7|384|Did|stored|is|381|0x595959|continue|course|txt__default_6UEzWWqBnPH|SAP|module|||180'.split('|'),0,{}))`

Answer (score 1):

The file has been encoded by Dean Edwards's [JavaScript Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/). You can use following online tool to unpack the file:
http://jsbeautifier.org/

The main content of the file seems to be a string in XML format as metadata for the slide.